# Programmatically redefine android resource colors

Tags: android, colors, resources

I have defined the various colors I want to use in my app as resources
eg.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="hedder_color">#FFFFFF</color>
    <color name="text_color">#7A7A7A</color>
    <color name="background">#0044AA</color>
</resources>
```

and then I use them throughout the app.

But... I need to make it so that the user can change these colors on the fly. So the question is, is there any way to programatically change these colors? So, for example, the user chooses a new background color and my code redefines

```
<color name="background">#0044AA</color>
```

as this new color. In all future use of the app the background color is now the new color chosen by the user.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: No, that's not possible.

Answer (score 1):

For all I know, resources are loaded statically on apk compilation and can not be changed. Please consider creating a separate class for that, which will hold the background color informaton.

```
public static class BackgroundColorHolder{
private int backgroundColor;

public BackgroundColorHolder(Context context){
    /*  Obtain the basic color from resources  */
    backgroundColor = context.getResources().getColor(R.color.background);
}

public int getCurrentBackgroundColor(){
    return backgroundColor;
}

public void changeBackgroundColor(int newColor){
    backgroundColor = newColor;
    /*  Some kind of notification for all of the affected views  */
}
```

}

Comment: That looks like a good idea albeit a little more complicated than I was hoping for! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Kelevandos's Answer was a big help but as it didn't give a definitive yes or no and the suggestion still left a lot of work to be done so I thought I'd up vote him but add some more myself rather than accepting it as the answer.

The answer is.. No. The resources cannot be redefined.

In the end I made a class that saved the users colors in shared preferences and then had methods for changing colors / redrawing drawables etc for each different view type. I then had a set Colors function in each activity which fed that activity's view's to the methods that would change them.